# Negative wavelength in the double-split experiment

Tags: double-slit-experiment

In the double-slit experiment, according to Wikipedia,

> the spacing of the fringes ($w$) at distance $z$ from the slits is given by $\displaystyle w = z\frac{\lambda}{d} \quad (\Leftrightarrow wd = z\lambda)$.

where $d$ is the distance between the slits and $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the light.

In a system where the distance from the slits is equal to the wavelength of the light we have $wd = \lambda^2$ or $\lambda = \pm\sqrt{wd}$.

What is the meaning of the negative wavelength?

Comment: Why do you think there should be a meaning of negative wavelength? Not every solution to an equation has to be physically meaningful.

Comment: Well that is what I was thinking but then on the other hand there could be just something I was not aware of. How would you explain that there's no hidden magic in that negative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The same argument could be said about $w=z\lambda/d$. For any positive $w$ allows solutions $z,\lambda>0$ and $z,\lambda<0$.

   So if you're looking for the meaning of $\lambda<0$, you are equivalently looking for solutions $z<0$. Given that $z$ is the distance to the screen, I don't think there's any physical meaning.
2. That equation you are using relies on the small angle approximation $\sin\theta\approx\theta\approx\tan(\theta)=w/z,$ where $\theta$ is measured relative to the normal. Since you're setting the screen amazingly close, I doubt the resulting equation has any meaning whatsoever.